# Is it possible getting all parameters of a field

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I need is returning all the parameters from field :

Example :

```
Class MyClass(models.Model):
    field = models.Charfield(blank = True, null = True)
```

I want to return all the parameters of "field" from "MyClass".

Here, it should be the parameters blank and null.

Comment: Do you mean all the parameters you've set or *all* the parameters? What have you tried? Can I ask, why do you need them?

Comment: Right, in fact, I added the "through" parameter, and I need to check in some views which fields have the "through" parameter.

Comment: Surely, that uses an overridden model? So the models that have the parameter are the one's you have created

Comment: Yes, it is an overridden model. But I don't understand how can I check if my field is using the "through" parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a model `MyModel`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
```

You can get the field using the [Meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/).

```
>>> field = MyModel._meta.get_field('my_field')
```

You can then use the `deconstruct` method to get the kwargs that were passed to the field when it was instantiated.

```
>>> name, path, args, kwargs = field.deconstruct()
>>> print(kwargs)
{u'max_length': 100}
```

Comment: To continue the example, it should be: `field = MyModel._meta.get_field('my_field')`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not really get the purpose of getting the parameters, but I think you can use '***vars***'. It's kind of wrap for '__dict__'.
As django model fields have '__dict__' attribute, '***vars***' will give you access to the field's parameters as follow:

```
def has_parameter(field_name, parameter_name):
    parameter_dict = vars(field_name)
    return not parameter_dict.get(parameter_name) == None
```

if equal to None means it's not set yet otherwise it's set or has a default value.

in you case: `>>> has_parameter(field_name,'through')`